# Scope of variable declared in for-loop, javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm getting an error in eclipse:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
    ...
}
...
while (someCondition) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bar; i++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The loops are using the same variable name. Eclipse gives me a warning that `'i' is already defined`. It does not give me a warning if i remove the var som the second for-loop.

AFAIK the variables declared in a for-loop (`i` in this case) has the same scope as the loop.

Is Eclipse correct? Are those `i`-variables in the same scope?

Comment: Yep, eclipse is correct.

Comment: I think you come from c/c++ background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local variables in JavaScript are scoped to the enclosing function. Thus, both `i` have the same scope.

To illustrate,

```
function f() {
  ...
  for (var i = ...; ...; ...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function f() {
  var i;
  ...
  for (i = ...; ...; ...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `i`-variables are in the same scope, because JavaScript variables traditionally have `functional scope`.

### Functional scope :

Functional scope means Variables are known within [**the function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) it is declared in, from the moment they are declared onwards.

Functionally scoped variables are created like this :

```
var myVariable = "Some text";
```

Functional scope can be understood like this :

```
// i IS NOT known here

function doSomething() {
    // i IS NOT known here
    for (var i = 0; i < bar; i++) {
        // i IS known here
    }
    // i IS known here
}

// i IS NOT known here
```

---

#### Block scope

The most recent JavaScript specs now also allow block Scope : Variables are known within [**the block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) it is declared in, from the moment they are declared onwards.

Block scope variables are created like this :

```
let myVariable = "Some text";
```

Block scope can be understood like this :

```
// i IS NOT known here

function doSomething() {
    // i IS NOT known here
    for (let i = 0; i < bar; i++) {
        // i IS known here
    }
    // i IS NOT known here
}

// i IS NOT known here
```

---

#### The difference between both scopes

To understand the difference between functional scope and block scope, consider the following code :

```
// i IS NOT known here
// j IS NOT known here

function loop(arr) {
    // i IS NOT known here
    // j IS NOT known here

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        // i IS known here
        // j IS NOT known here
    };

    // i IS known here
    // j IS NOT known here

    for( let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++ ) {
        // i IS known here
        // j IS known here
    };

    // i IS known here
    // j IS NOT known here
}

// i IS NOT known here
// j IS NOT known here
```

Here, we can see that our variable `j` is only known in the first for loop, but not before and after. Yet, our variable `i` is known in the entire function from the moment it is defined onward.

---

#### Is it safe to use block scope variables today?

Whether or not it is safe to use today, depends on your environment :

- If you're writing server-side JavaScript code ([**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org/en/)), you can safely use the `let` statement.
- If you're writing client-side JavaScript code and use a transpiler (like [**Traceur**](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)), you can safely use the `let` statement, however your code is likely to be anything but optimal with respect to performance.
- If you're writing client-side JavaScript code and don't use a transpiler, you need to consider browser support.

  Today, Feb 23 2016, these are some browsers that either don't support `let` or have only partial support :

  - **Internet explorer 10** and below (no support)
  - **Firefox 43** and below (no support)
  - **Safari 9** and below (no support)
  - **Opera Mini 8** and below (no support)
  - **Android browser 4** and below (no support)
  - **Opera 36** and below (partial support)
  - **Chome 51** and below (partial support)

[image]

---

#### How to keep track of browser support

For an up-to-date overview of which browsers support the `let` statement at the time of your reading this answer, see [**this `Can I Use` page**](http://caniuse.com/#search=let).